# Given a URL hash string, ask AppRouter to resolve the designated controller method

Tags: marionette

I have an AppRouter and a Controller.  Now on this link `<a class="myLink" href="#foo/123">link</a>` I do not want the browser url be changed, so

```
$('.myLink').click( function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();

  //  do something else
  //  ...

  var href = $(this).attr('href');  // #foo/123
  // now I want to use AppRouter/Controller to do as they are designed to.
});
```

---

```
var MyRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  appRoutes: {  "foo/:id": "doFoo" }
});

App.on('before:start', function () {
  App.router = new myRouter({
    controller: new myController()
  });
});
```

**Question:** having a string `#foo/123` (which is not on browser's URL bar) is it possible to ask the router to resolve the controller method `doFoo`?

Or to tell the router to directly invoke `doFoo` without telling me it is `doFoo`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you should probably not do it. A better route would be to use an event.

This is how you do what you are suggesting:

```
var x = "foo/123";
_.select(Backbone.history.handlers, function(handler) {
  return handler.route.test(x);
});
```

Here is a better route:

```
$('.myLink').click( function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  App.vent.trigger("do controller handler");
});

controller.listenTo(App.vent, "do controller handler", controller.handler);
```

Comment: I will need the `handler.route` method.  Now that I can find which handler to use,  how to run the callback?   [1] returns true but `Backbone.history.handlers[1].callback()` gives error: `Cannot read property 'slice' of null`

Comment: You probably aren't passing the correct arguments to the handler.

Comment: Sorry may I ask for more: `Backbone.history.handlers[the_index].callback(the_id)`   is the good way to invoke `doFoo` in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Hubbs answered this question: **'to resolve the designated controller method'**.

For the followup question **'how to run the method found'**, here is the answer extending Andrew Hubbs'

```
var href = "foo/123";   // url hash, after #

// _.find returns the first match
var handler = _.find(Backbone.history.handlers, function(handler) {
  return handler.route.test(href);
});

if ( !!handler ) {
  handler.callback.apply( null, handler.route.exec(href) );
}
```

Why null:
Null is the value of 'this' provided for the call to 'callback'.  See [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Don't know what the 'this' should be.  Giving null works.  Omitting it results in js error:  `Cannot read property 'slice' of null`